# Categories not showing in navigation bar of first multi website magento installation

Tags: magento-1.9

I have multi website magento installation. Made two websites [image]

Both are running on separate sub domains. But however only dropshippingstore website is showing categories in the navigation bar not the retail website for customers . But I have assigned same root category to both.

Site 1 navigation menu
[image]

No sub categories showing here.

Whereas in second website sub categories are showing in navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding categories to the default category and now it showed up on both websites.